# Form saving error PHP MYSQL

Tags: mysql, php

I have a form that saves 2 narratives and a select option.  If I place to many characters in the narrative box it will not save to the mysql table, but if I decrease the characters then it will save just fine.

I have set php.ini to allow longer post time var sizes so im not sure if I am missing anything else in the php.ini that anyone can think of.

Thank for any suggestions.

Comment: How many is "too many"?  (That is, find out approximately what the cutoff it.)  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (so we can see how the target is declared).  Are you using `method=POST`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your data is to large for the constraints placed on the table/columns that you are trying to populate.

Take a look at the [Data Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) of the columns you are adding to and the [Limits of those Data Types](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/datatypes.php), then compare that to your values that are producing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limit on the length of data you can save into your database field, then you *might* want to prevent the User from entering any more than that.

That's precisely what the **maxlength** attribute is for!

```
<textarea ... maxlength='2000' ...>
</textarea>
```